# How to assign array elements to private variable and use them in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

```
/*
c - csis
a - acct
b - busn
p - phys

*/
class CourseInfo {

  private String courseTitle;
  private double coursePrice;
  private int courseSeatsAvail;
  private String courseDesc;
  private char courseType;

  private static String empPassword;

  CourseInfo(String crseTitle, double crsePrice, int crseSeats, String crseDesc, char type) {

    courseTitle = crseTitle;
    coursePrice = crsePrice;
    courseSeatsAvail = crseSeats;
    courseDesc = crseDesc;
    courseType = type;
  }

  /*
   * Finish the class with the set/get methods
   */
}

///////////////////////////////

class CourseList {

  CourseInfo[] courseList;

  public void createList() {

    courseList = new CourseInfo[11];

    courseList[0] = new CourseInfo("acct110", 375.49, 35, "this course teaches \nbasic accounting practice", 'a');
    courseList[1] = new CourseInfo("busn110", 375.49, 35, "this course teaches \nbasic business pratice", 'b');
    courseList[2] = new CourseInfo("busn240", 375.49, 35, "this course teaches \nadvance business pratice", 'b');
    courseList[3] = new CourseInfo("csis110", 375.49, 2, "this course teaches \nbasic computing pratice", 'c');
    courseList[4] = new CourseInfo("csis220", 375.49, 35, "this course teaches \nR language", 'c');
    courseList[5] = new CourseInfo("csis290", 375.49, 25, "this course teaches \nbasic hardware pratice", 'c');
    courseList[6] = new CourseInfo("csis340", 375.49, 35, "this course teaches \nadvance CPU tech", 'c');
    courseList[7] = new CourseInfo("csis420", 375.49, 17, "this course teaches \nbasic computer graphics", 'c');
    courseList[8] = new CourseInfo("csis491", 375.49, 3, "this course teaches \nbasic game programming", 'c');
    courseList[9] = new CourseInfo("phys120", 499.19, 30, "this course teaches \nbasic physics theory", 'p');
    courseList[10] = new CourseInfo("phys240", 399.99, 35, "this course teaches \nbasic quantum mechanics", 'p');

  }
}
```

I'm trying to access the data in CreateList from a different .java file but my instructor wants me to do it in this specific way with private variables and sets and gets and I have no idea how to proceed. I know how to create basic sets and gets but I don't understand how they're meant to work with the CourseInfo constructor.

Comment: Two hints:  `private CourseInfo[] courseList` and `public CourseInfo[] getCourseInfo()`.

Comment: You mention `CreateList` but it's not described or shown in your code. What is it? What do arrays have to do with your code?

Comment: @erickson `CreateList` likely refers to their class method `CourseList.createList()`

Comment: @CubeJockey Okay, somehow I didn't see that "below the fold." My apologies.

Answer (score -1):

'Getters' and 'setters' are used to encapsulate variables / objects in Java. This means (as your instructor said), you should be making the variables **private** and the getters and setters **public**.

**For example:**

```
private String courseTitle;
```

This variable is only accessible within the class, so to be able to get this variable from outside the class (i.e. from wherever you are using the `CourseList` from), you need to create a **getter** (to get the variable) and a **setter** (to change the value of the variable). As follows:

```
// Getter
public String getCourseTitle() {
    return this.courseTitle;
}

// Setter
public void setCourseTitle(String newCourseTitle) {
    this.courseTitle = newCourseTitle;
}
```

You can read more about encapsulation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

Now, to retrieve the values, use the **getter**, as follows (assuming courseInfo is a CourseInfo object):

```
String data = courseInfo.getCourseTitle();
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why they downvoted?

Comment: When I try and make a CourseInfo object in my calling class (CourseRegister) using `CourseInfo courseInfo = new CourseInfo();` 
I get 
`CourseRegister.java:13: error: constructor CourseInfo in class CourseInfo cannot be applied to given types;
   CourseInfo courseInfo = new CourseInfo();
                           ^
  required: String,double,int,String,char
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: This is because you don't have a constructor with no parameters. All you have to do is add a constructor into your CourseInfo class, as follows: 'public CourseInfo() { }'

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this for each variables create his set and get method like:
      private String courseTitle;

```
 public String getCourseTitle() {
    return courseTitle;
}

public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle) {
    this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
}
```

And in `CourseList` class try to set the value of `courseTitle` like this:

```
setCourseTitle("value of courseTitle");
```

Than you can get it like this:

```
String var = getCourseTitle();
```

And use the value where do you want for example add it in array `courseList`.